# Java : Getter /setter for Arraylist<Object>

Tags: java, setter, getter

so i have :

```
    ArrayList<data> mi = new ArrayList<data>();
```

i have a Query which do following :

```
while (rs.next()) {

            mi.add(new users());
            mi.get(i).name= rs.getString("name");
            mi.get(i).pass= rs.getString("pass");
            }
```

It works but i want it with Getter/setters like :

```
mi.get(i).setname( rs.getString("name"));
```

Edit : Misspelling i had it so

Why cant i call the methode?

Comment: You need to read about methods in java.

Comment: Even if ArrayList.get works in linear time, I'd still prefer setting the user's data directly in a user's reference before putting it in the list.

Comment: instaed of mi.get(i).setname()= rs.getString("name"); try mi.get(i).setname(rs.getString("name")); ... be sure setName access modifiers it should be accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `users` class should have a public `setname(String name)` method, which sets the `name` field of `user` class

then, `mi.get(i).setname(rs.getString("name"));` will work

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
mi.get(i).setname(rs.getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is java. You cannot have such assignment

```
setname() = rs.getString("name")
```

It does not make sense. You shall set it as argument:

```
object.setName(rs.getString("name"))
```

Also please respect java naming conventions: Class has CamelCase, methods start with lower first character and then continue with camel case as well: `setUserName`

Answer (score 0):

with

`mi.get(i).setname()`

you call the method `setname()`. The result (if any) is not a variable name and you cannot assign a value to it.

If your class has a method `setname(String s)` then use it as usual in Java:

```java
mi.get(i).setname(rs.getString("name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the below approach

```
while (rs.next()) {
Users user = new Users();
user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
user.setPass(rs.getString("pass"));
mi.add(user);
}
```

Seems neater to set the values in your object and then adding them to the list.